# How to show/hide divs when a if/else condition is met in ReactJS from a data coming from JSON?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, prop

How can a div be shown/hidden when a condition is met in React, when the data comes from a JSON array? I've got this code so far, but when I change the value of `isPassed={resultPass.pass}` to `isPassed={resultPass.failed}` it still shows the result as `pass`.

The closest example I've found is [this](https://codepen.io/nmcnmc/pen/EoaQKg), but it does not fetch value from a JSON ( var resultPass in my code), but just assigns true/false value to a const.

```
var resultPass = {
  "pass": "passpass",
  "fail": "failfail"
}

function Passed(props) {
  return <div class="result-pass"><h3>passpass</h3></div>;
}

function Failed(props) {
  <div class="result-fail"><h3>failfail</h3></div>;
} 

function ResultDisplay(props) {
  const isPassed = props.isPassed;
  if (isPassed) {
    return <Passed />;
  } 
  return <Failed />;
}

// When resultPass.pass is changed resultPass.fail it still shows as pass
render(<ResultDisplay isPassed={resultPass.pass} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here is my [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0o7yw8910n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not properly checking the prop of `ResultDisplay`.

```
  const isPassed = props.isPassed;
  if (isPassed) {
    return <Passed />;
  } 
  return <Failed />;
```

`isPassed` will be either the string "passpass" or "failfail", but since your `if` statement is making a basic equivalency check, it is type converting both of your strings to a `true` boolean value. So, your `if` statement always evaluates to `true` and you're always returning `<Passed />`.

The proper way to check the equivalency of a string is with the more strict identity operator (`===`) which will not convert type and ensure that you're checking for the exact same string.

```
  const isPassed = props.isPassed;
  if (isPassed === "passpass") {
    return <Passed />;
  } 
  return <Failed />;
```

You also need to ensure that your `Failed()` function returns something, otherwise it will not work properly.

```
function Passed(props) {
  return <div class="result-pass"><h3>passpass</h3></div>;
}

function Failed(props) {
  return <div class="result-fail"><h3>failfail</h3></div>;
}
```

Comment: When I add ==="passpass" I get this error: "Invariant Violation
Failed(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null." Any idea why?

Comment: @Amma Yes, because your `Failed` function does not have a `return` statement. :)

Comment: That was it - now it works, thanks! 
https://codesandbox.io/s/j36935115w

Answer (score 2):

That is because `if (isPassed) {` always evaluate to `true`. You should check the if condition properly like this

```
if (isPassed === "passpass") {
    return <Passed />;
  } 
  return <Failed />;
```